# Python multiprocessing - return values from 3 different functions

Tags: python, process, multiprocessing

I need to execute 3 functions in parallel and retrieve a value from each of them.

Here my code:

```
def func1():
   ...
    return x

def func2():
   ...
    return y

def func3():
   ...
    return z


p1 = Process(target=func1)
first = p1.start()
p2 = Process(target=func2)
second= p2.start()
p3 = Process(target=func3)
third = p3.start()
p1.join()
p2.join()
p3.join()
```

but first, second and third seems to be 'NoneType' objects.

What's wrong in my code?

Thanks

Comment: `p3.start()` starts the thread, of course it's going to return `None`.

Comment: There is a difference between threads and multiprocessing. Thus, the proposed duplicate is not entirely correct.

Answer (score 4):

There are a few different ways to solve this. The simplest one is to use a `multiprocessing.Pool` and the `apply_async` function:

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func1():
    x = 2
    return x

def func2():
    y = 1
    return y

def func3():
    z = 5
    return z

if __name__ == '__main__':
    with Pool(processes=3) as pool:
        r1 = pool.apply_async(func1, ())
        r2 = pool.apply_async(func2, ())
        r3 = pool.apply_async(func3, ())

        print(r1.get(timeout=1))
        print(r2.get(timeout=1))
        print(r3.get(timeout=1))
```

The `multiprocessing.Pool` is a rahter helpful construct that takes care of the underlying communication between processes, by setting up pipes and queues and what else is needed. The most common use case is to use it together with different data to the same function (distributing the work) using the `.map` function. However, it can also be used for different functions, by e.g. the `.apply_async` construct like I am doing here.

This, however, does not work from the interpreter but must be stored as as `.py` file and run using `python filename.py`.

Comment: Is there a way to add a 'barrier'? That is, the master process should continue after last slave process ended

Comment: Well, yes, you can block hard by not setting a `timeout` value in your `.get()` calls. Also, if you have a `timeout` the get call can fail, with a `TimeoutError` which really needs to be handled (even though I did not).

Answer (score 0):

Upon understanding your use case, I would suggest using multiprocessing.Pool. Similar to @JohanL solution.

```
from multiprocessing import Pool

def func1(x):
    return x*x

def func2(y):
    return y*y

def func3(z):
    return z*z

p = Pool(3)
print(p.apply(func1, (2, )))
print(p.apply(func2, (3, )))
print(p.apply(func3, (4, )))
```

Comment: Functions seems to not run in parallel.....

Comment: This is a basic example of data parallelism using pool. You may want to check the [documentation](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) once.

Comment: No, they do not run in parallel. As stated in the documentation: _apply(func[, args[, kwds]])
Equivalent of the apply() built-in function. It blocks until the result is ready, so apply_async() is better suited for performing work in parallel. Additionally, func is only executed in one of the workers of the pool._

Comment: Hmm, interesting, makes sense! Then I feel @JohanL solution is more suitable. And yeah async func call in multiprocess is better than blocking it till each func returns the result which is in the case of Pool.apply.