# Utilizing the multi processing tool with Numpy Python

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, python-multiprocessing

I am trying to utilize multi processing tool with numpy arrays. I want to run `func1()` and `func2()` simultaneously and then use `np.concatenate()` and place `Solution_1` and `Solution_2` together. How will I be able to do such a thing?

Modules:

```
import multiprocessing
import numpy as np
```

Code:

```
Numbers = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
def func1():
     Solution_1 = Numbers + 10 
     return Solution_1 
def func2():
     Solution_2 = Numbers * 10
     return Solution_2 
#setting up the multi processing vars     
p1 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func1)
p2 = multiprocessing.Process(target=func2)

#running the multi processes 
if __name__ == "__main__":
    p1.start()
    p2.start()
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

For example:

```
import multiprocessing as mp
import numpy as np
num_cores = mp.cpu_count()

Numbers = np.array([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12])
def func1():
     Solution_1 = Numbers + 10
     return Solution_1
def func2():
     Solution_2 = Numbers * 10
     return Solution_2

# Getting ready my cores, I left one aside
pool = mp.Pool(num_cores-1)
# This is to use all functions easily
functions = [func1, func2]
# This is to store the results
solutions = []
for function in functions:
    solutions.append(pool.apply(function, ()))
```

`solutions` looks like:

```
[array([11, 12, 13, 14, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20, 21, 22]),
 array([ 10,  20,  30,  40,  50,  60,  70,  80,  90, 100, 110, 120])]
```

You could place that directly in a dataframe:

```
solutions = pd.DataFrame(solutions)
print(solutions)
    0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8    9   10   11
0  11  12  13  14  15  16  17  18  19   20   21   22
1  10  20  30  40  50  60  70  80  90  100  110  120
```

I see in a similar cases / **alternatives**:

- Global Variables, this is very similar to the original case post here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/40399562/7127519
- `apply_async`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48933782/7127519
- A shared variable to communicate: [How can I recover the return value of a function passed to multiprocessing.Process?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10415028/how-can-i-recover-the-return-value-of-a-function-passed-to-multiprocessing-proce)
- `multiprocessing.Manager()`: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10415215/7127519

And others.

Comment: When I run the code I get an error saying `AttributeError: 'dict' object has no attribute 'append` in the `solutions.append(pool.apply(function, ()))` bit of the code.

Comment: Sorry, that was because I defined solutions as dict instead of a list. Solve now.

Comment: For some reason it runs forever and does not stop

Comment: Where does it get stack? in the for?

Comment: I will upload a snapshot to the issue perhaps that would help

Comment: It could be related as well with the number of cores of your machine. Feel free to play around with `pool = mp.Pool(num_cores-1)`.